# I try to update image with ajax in laravel but only details are update image is not update. How can i solve this?

Tags: ajax, laravel, fileupdate

> Hi every one, I am using laravel 8, and i want to update data using model, now i am facing little problem. The Problem is only details are update but file or image did not updated, i give every thing in bellow,

Blade Code: THis is my datatable

```
<table class="table display" width="100%" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @php
                    $i=0;
                    @endphp
                    @foreach ($banner as $item )

                    <tr id="banner-{{ $item->id }}">
                        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->title }}</td>
                        <td><img src="{{ asset('/assets/image/banner/'.$item->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 100px; height:100px"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" class="status" id="status" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Deactive" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" {{ $item->status == 'Active' ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editbanner({{ $item->id }})"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger deletebtn"><i class="mdi mdi-trash-can"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Update Model** here is data update model, that i create for update data.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="BannerEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Insert Position & Salary</h3>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul id="BannerForm_errorlist"></ul>
            <form class="forms-sample" id="bannereditform" method="post">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title<small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
                    <input type="text" id="title1" name="title1" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Banner Image<small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
                    <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1" class="form-control" />
                </div>


                <div class="text-center pb-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Part** This is Ajax code for data fetching and data uploading

```
    function editbanner(id) {
    $.get("/banner/edit/" + id, function(banner) {
        $('#id').val(banner.id);
        $('#title1').val(banner.title);
        $('#BannerEditModal').modal("toggle");
    });
}

$('#bannereditform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let id = $('#id').val();
    var title1 = $('#title1').val();
    var image1 = $('#image1').val();
    let _token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
    console.log(image1);

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT"
        , url: "/banner/update"
        , data: {
            id: id
            , title1: title1
            , image1: image1
            , _token: _token
        , }
        , dataType: "json"
        , success: function(response) {
            // console.log(response);
            $('#banner' + response.id + 'td:nth-child(1)').text(response.title1);
            $('#banner' + response.id + 'td:nth-child(2)').val(response.image1);

            $('#BannerEditModal').modal("toggle");
            // location.reload();
            $('#bannereditform')[0].reset();

        }
    });

});
```

**Controller**

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    $banner = Banner::find($request->id);
    $banner->title = $request->input('title1');
    if($request->hasFile('image1')){
        $destination = public_path().'/assets/image/banner/'.$banner->image;
        if(File::exists($destination)){
            File::delete($destination);
        }
        $image = $request->file('image1');
        $image_name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path().'/assets/image/banner/',$image_name);
        $banner->image = $image_name;
    }
    $banner->save();
    return response()->json($banner);
}
```

**Route** Here is my data fatching and data updating route

```
Route::get('/banner/edit/{id}', "App\Http\Controllers\BannerController@edit")->name('banner.edit');
Route::put('/banner/update', "App\Http\Controllers\BannerController@update")->name('banner.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **enctype** in your modal form:
The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

**Note**: The enctype attribute can be used only if method="post".

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Insert Position & Salary</h3>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul id="BannerForm_errorlist"></ul>
        <form class="forms-sample" id="bannereditform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title<small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
                <input type="text" id="title1" name="title1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Banner Image<small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
                <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1" class="form-control" />
            </div>


            <div class="text-center pb-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax** : to send form files and data to Back-end we are using Form Data objects:

```
   $('#bannereditform').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

let formData = new FormData($('#bannereditform')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT"
    , url: "/banner/update"
    , data:formData, 
    , dataType: "json", 
      processData: false
    , success: function(response) {
        // console.log(response);
        $('#banner' + response.id + 'td:nth-child(1)').text(response.title1);
        $('#banner' + response.id + 'td:nth-child(2)').val(response.image1);

        $('#BannerEditModal').modal("toggle");
        // location.reload();
        $('#bannereditform')[0].reset();

    }
});})
```

Comment: how i get this type of error, "TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: @MohammadHasibulhasan send screen shot

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/qqo4g9ptwhr5nyx2z6fz9/h?dl=0&rlkey=wc206x3njide87t0v5kp6q9sr 

 check thus screen short

Comment: @MohammadHasibulhasan add processData: false to ajax request I have edited the answer check please it will work enjoy

Comment: not working still get error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the way you getting value from #image from

`var image1 = $('#image1').val();`

to

`var image1 = $('#image1').prop('files')[0]`

Comment: this not work for me....

Comment: wrap with formData. 
`var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#image1').prop('files')[0]);`